# Как написать подсчет Определителя Больших Матриц методом Гаусса с выбором глобального главного элемента?

Tags: алгоритм, матрицы, численные-методы

Нужно написать подсчет определителя матрицы, с помощью метода Гаусса с выбором глобального главного элемента. 
Все алгоритмы которые я нахожу, это просто метод Гаусса. А мне нужен частный случай с выбором глобального главного элемента. Хотелось бы увидеть четкий алгоритм.

Comment: может с выбором главного элемента? глобальный главный элемент - это просто главный, так?

Comment: @seniorpomidor выбор главного глобального элемента это когда элемент выбирается не в строчке или столбце  отдельно, а просматривается вся матрица целиком.

Comment: так наибольшой по модулью и есть главный глобальный элемент, и нужно определить этот элемент и привести ее к треугольной форме. поправьте, если ошибаюсь

Comment: @SenoirPomidor  спасибо большое за разъяснение. Я бы был очень благодарен, если бы вы прислали полный алгоритм.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Запишем расширенную прямоугольную матрицу коэффициентов системы 
[image: прямоугольная матрица]

Среди элементов матрицы [image] выберем наибольший по модулю, **называемый главным**, элемент. Пусть им будет элемент [image]. Строка с номером *m*, содержащая главный элемент, называется главной строкой.

Далее вычисляем множители [image] для всех [image].

Затем матрица [image: введите сюда описание изображения] преобразуется так: к каждой i-й, неглавной строке, прибавим почленно главную строку, умножив её на *m<sub>i</sub>*. В результате получим матрицу, у которой все элементы `l`-го столбца, за исключением [image], равны 0. Отбрасывая этот столбец и главную строку, получаем новую матрицу *S*<sub>1</sub> с меньшим на единицу числом строк и столбцов.

Над матрицей *S*<sub>1</sub> повторяем те же операции, после чего получаем матрицу *S*<sub>2</sub> и т.д. Эти преобразования продолжаются до тех пор, пока не получится матрица, содержащая одну строку из двух элементов, которая тоже считается главной. Затем объединяем все главные строки, начиная с последней. После некоторой перестановки они образуют треугольную матрицу, эквивалентную исходной. На этом заканчивается прямой ход метода Гаусса с выбором главного элемента.

Далее находим [image], решая систему с треугольной матрицей. Это обратный ход.

Напоминаю, что это возможно в том случае, когда [image: введите сюда описание изображения]. Добиться выполнения этого условия можно, переставляя элементы строк и столбцов матрицы

Источники

Н. Н. Меркулова, М. Д. Михайлов
«Методы приближенных вычислений». [Ссылка](https://old.math.tsu.ru/EEResources/cm/)

[Википедия](https://ru.wikiversity.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B_%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC_%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

Comment: Так этот алгоритм не отвечает на главный вопрос, как считать определители?

Comment: вы таким образом грубо говоря обнуляете столбцы, кроме перовой строки, чтобы матрица стала треугольной, до тех пор, пока матрица не будет иметь вид меньше 2на2. тогда подсчет определителья будет простой.  так понятнее?

Comment: // как считать определители?
Линейные преобразования, используемые в методе Гаусса не меняют определитель. Определитель треугольной матрицы равен произведению диагональных элементов. Так что используем прямой проход, чтобы свести матрицу к треугольной, а потом перемножаем элементы на диагонали.